# python panda :how to delete row from csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

i want to delete empty row(last row) from csv file

I searched a lot about the solution but didn't found

[image: panda]

Comment: do you want to delete the row if any column is empty?

Comment: I see an empty _column_, not an empty _row_.

Comment: yes delete row which has empty column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,''], 'B': [4,5,'', 6]})
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df = df.dropna()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0  5.0
```

You can delete column using `del`

```
del df['column_name']
```

Comment: @eslam ahmed you mean toal column

Comment: @eslamahmed check now

Answer (score 0):

This works I think -

```py
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Column name'])
```